# Is there an idiomatic alternative to nil-punning in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, null, option-type

I'm reading some Clojure code at the moment that has a bunch of uninitialised values as `nil` for a numeric value in a record that gets passed around.

Now lots of the Clojure libraries [treat this as idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045404/why-clojure-idiom-prefer-to-return-nil-instead-of-empty-list-like-scheme). Which means that it is an accepted convention.

But it also leads to `NullPointerException`, because not all the Clojure core functions can handle a `nil` as input. (Nor should they).

Other languages have the concept of `Maybe` or `Option` to proxy the value in the event that it is null, as a way of mitigating the `NullPointerException` risk. This is possible in Clojure - [but not very common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839697/why-is-the-use-of-maybe-option-not-so-pervasive-in-clojure).

You can do some tricks with `fnil` but it doesn't solve every problem.

Another alternative is simply to set the uninitialised value to a symbol like `:empty-value` to force the user to handle this scenario explicitly in all the handling code. But this isn't really a big step-up from `nil` - because you don't really discover all the scenarios (in other people's code) until run-time.

My question is: **Is there an idiomatic alternative to nil-punning in Clojure?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you've read this lispcast [post](http://www.lispcast.com/nil-punning) on `nil-punning`, but I do think it makes a pretty good case for why it's idiomatic and covers various important considerations that I didn't see mentioned in those other SO questions.

Basically, `nil` is a *first-class* thing in clojure. Despite its inherent conventional meaning, it *is* a proper value, and can be treated as such in many contexts, and in a context-dependent way. This makes it more flexible and powerful than `null` in the host language.

For example, something like this won't even compile in java:

```
if(null) {
....
}
```

Where as in clojure, `(if nil ...)` will work just fine. So there are many situations where you can use nil **safely**. I'm yet to see a java codebase that isn't *littered* with code like `if(foo != null) { ...` everywhere. Perhaps java 8's `Optional` will change this.

I think where you *can* run into issues quite easily is in java interop scenarios where you are dealing with actual `null`s. A good clojure wrapper library can also help shield you from this in many cases, and its one good reason to *prefer* one over direct java interop where possible.

In light of this, you may want to re-consider fighting this current. But since you are asking about alternatives, here's one I think is great: [prismatic's schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema). Schema has a `Maybe` schema (and many other useful ones as well), and it works quite nicely in many scenarios. The library is quite popular and I have used it with success. FWIW, it is recommended in the recent [clojure applied](https://pragprog.com/book/vmclojeco/clojure-applied) book.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there an idiomatic alternative to nil-punning in Clojure?*

No. As [leeor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34613164/1562315) explains, nil-punning is idiomatic. But it's not as prevalent as in Common Lisp, where (I'm told) an empty list equates to nil.

Clojure used to work this way, but the CL functions that deal with lists correspond to Clojure functions that deal with sequences in general. And these sequences may be lazy, so there is a premium on unifying lazy sequences with others, so that any laziness can be preserved.  I think this evolution happened about Clojure 1.2. Rich described it in detail [here](http://clojure.org/lazier).

If you want option/maybe types, take a look at the [core.typed](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) library. In contrast to Prismatic Schema, this operates at compile time.