# How can I attempt to iterate a Hash in Ruby when the object may be nil?

Tags: ruby

I find myself having to do this all the time, and when I'm in a hurry I wrap it in a conditional:

```
if !myhash.blank?
  hash.each do |k,v|
    do_something
  end
end
```

or:

```
myhash.map{|k,v| do_something} unless myhash.blank?
```

There must be something cleaner.

Comment: You could use a "null" hash that you set to return some acceptable default value. That is, you would define hash as `hash = my_hash || default_hash`. Then you don't need a conditional each time you refer to `my_hash`; just when it's first defined.

Comment: Since an empty hash is a fine value to be looped over, you don't need the `blank?`: `if myhash`

Comment: If you have `nil` where you expect a `Hash`, that's a bug, and the correct response is to fix the bug so you don't get `nil` in the first place, not to work around the `nil`! And if you "find yourself having to do this all the time", then you have a *lot* of bugs, and you should tighten up your design, development, testing, code review, and QA processes (and, ultimately, your *hiring* processes, so you don't hire programmers that write such silly bugs in the first place)!

Comment: Thanks so much Jorg. I write the code from home for my business. Sorry for being so silly. But since we're giving out advice, my advice to you is to work on your manners. I don't care what your score is on SO, your arrogance is showing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/o3fNPon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tend to use [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_h) to hide the "is it `nil`" test:

```
hash.to_h.each do |k,v|
  # something
end
```

If `hash` is already a Hash then `hash.to_h` is `hash`, if `hash.nil?` then `hash.to_h` is `{ }`.

Similarly, I use [`to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_a) for arrays:

```
array.to_a.each { |e| ... }
```

[`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_s) for strings, [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i) for integers (when I want to treat `nil` as zero), ...

Answer (score 5):

I would probably do either this:

```
(my_hash || {}).each do |k, v|
  # something
end
```

or this:

```
my_hash ||= {}
my_hash.each do |k, v|
  # something
end
```

Comment: +1 for the first snippet. I cannot say I like the second, though, variable re-bindings aren't too nice. Maybe later in the method you'll need the original value of `my_hash`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `rails`, you can say:

```
my_hash.try(:each) do |key, value|
  # code
end
```

[try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) will return `nil` if called on `nil` **or** if receiver does not respond to the method.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specifically iterate if not nil you could do something like

```
hash && hash.each do |x|
  # do something
end
```

But I find the `unless hash.nil?` to be more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash(myhash).each {|k,v| # whatevs }
```

Always returns a `Hash`. Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18894072/1076207

irb test:

```
# $ irb
# irb(main):001:0> Hash(myhash=nil).each {|k,v|}
# => {}
# irb(main):002:0> Hash(myhash={"a" => "b"}).each {|k,v|}
# => {"a"=>"b"}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved."